# Specific QPushButton style

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, qtstylesheets, qpushbutton

How can I customize the look of a QPushButton or QToolButton to look something like elementaryos's webpage "buttons"?

[image: Button images]

All I really want is the characteristic image position and the text on it's side, maybe if i'm lucky i can also get a border like that, but i don't really need the little description below the title :)
Can i do it only with StyleSheets, or do i have to subclass QPushButton/QAbstractButton/Something like that? I already searched everywhere but didn't found that level of customization without things like painting something in a *fixed* place, which is exactly what i **don't** want.

EDIT:
I really would like a solution that would get me a customizable button, not a fixed image one, something in the tracks of

```
MainWindowButton(QString(title), /*opt*/QString(description), QImage(icon));
```

Comment: The answer would depend on more specific requirements. You can achieve exactly what you see in your image with a style sheet and two images; an "up" image and a "down" (pressed) image. If however you want to merely specify the text and icon image and have the button widget render it stylized like the example then that would require a more complex solution, likely sub classing. You should edit your question to be more specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of approaches that may work.

You might first consider trying to compose a solution with a normal `QPushButton` with a `QVBoxLayout` on it. You could add three `QLabels`; one for the title text, one for the caption text and one for the image. Some CSS could probably be used to render the background image of the button for up and down and more CSS to style the text in the two labels and position the image on the third but you would then find that the labels don't shift down when the button is clicked.

I think the best solution involves direct painting. You could do this by sub classing a `QWidget` and overriding the `paintEvent()`. Render everything for the up state and shift everything over and down a bit for the down state.

You could achieve this without sub classing by rendering the up and down states to a `QImage` and styling a QPushbutton with them using CSS.

There are a number of combinations of these approaches too.

Comment: I ended up using QPainter and drawing the button by hand, and I got it all in a flexible MainButton(QString Title, QString Descrition, QImage Icon) class! :D thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can set the background as white with the icon in the right corner with some creative use of the border-image stylesheet property where the bottom border is as tall as the icon and the top, left and right borders are 0 pixels wide. You'll need to make a custom image that basically looks like the icon with a couple pixels width on the left and top that are white

http://doc.qt.digia.com/qq/qq20-qss.html#theboxmodel

The text you may have to do overriding paintEvent.