# GUI style for windows Qt application

Tags: windows, qt, user-interface, mfc, wxwidgets

How can i achieve this kind of look and feel with colored buttons and rounded corners in dialogs for a windows application?

i dont think it can be done using MFC , will wxWidgets or Qt help ? or any other platform?[image]

Comment: please write Qt, QT=QuickTime :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest and fastest way to achieve the same UI accross different platforms is to implement it in QML with Qt. Unlike widgets that get automatically styled appropriate to the underlying platform style, QML is entirely platform-independent. You could probably style regular widgets with CSS, or even by reimplementing drawing manually with arbitrary UI API, but it will not be nearly as easy.

Comment: hi , thanks for your reply. So just wanted to confirm , using wxwidgets on windows , we will NOT be able to get this type of UI, right? My only option is QT here.

Comment: It is possible, but won't be easy, and far from an optimal solution.

Answer (score 4):

You can design whatever the look & feel you are pursuing using `QSS`. Why don't you take a look at Qt Documentation ? There are plenty of examples & guidance available.

- [Stylesheet Examples](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/stylesheet-examples.html)
- [Stylesheet Reference](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/stylesheet-reference.html)
- [Stylesheet Syntax](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/stylesheet-syntax.html)
- [Customizing Qt Widgets Using Stylesheets](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/stylesheet-customizing.html)

But at times, you will need to override a control to achieve your goal. Like in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13655018/specific-qpushbutton-style). But I think your required look can be achieved via `QSS` alone.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.The links are of much help. I am a little less familiar with QT than wxwidgets, do we have options to create such a thing with wxwidgets? Any guidance will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It is easy to achieve such a look and feel with **any** GUI framework.

Choose the framework you are most comfortable with, RTFM, roll up your sleeves and get started.

On any framework you will find methods to draw bitmaps of any color and shape and to handle mouse clicks on them. What more do you need?

This is what GUI frameworks DO!  They also provide a default set of widgets for the bone lazy and the conventional.  You aren't one of those people. are you?

Comment: Reinventing the wheel, while possible, is not usually recommended. Also, various tools will require more or less efforts to do it. Just because some tool can do something doesn't mean it is the right tool to do it. It is possible to cut down a tree with a pocket knife, but I'd rather use a chainsaw.